# Eclipse Virgo Injected JPA EntityManager does not connect to Database

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0, datasource, eclipse-virgo

I am using Eclipse Virgo and I am trying to get annotation driven transaction management running but I keep running into the same issue.

Problem is that the EntityManager is injected and not null. But any query fails due to a connection error.

I used the setup according to [GreenPages](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/greenpages-documentation-2.4.0.RELEASE/docs/htmlsingle/greenpages-guide.html).

I have the following EntityManageFactory and TransactionManager configured

```
<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ShiftManagement" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform"
                value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="....." />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Also I have the following DataSources configured. Problem is, I tried them all, but when I try to connect to the database using a query, it doesn't work. Now, I am 100% sure that the credentials are OK, the DB is UP etc etc

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="rootroot" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <!-- TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED = 2 -->
    <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="2" />
    <!-- TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED = 1 -->
    <!-- <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="1" /> -->
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Error when using commons-dbcp

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:901)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
```

Using Spring Datasource

```
<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="rootroot" />
</bean>



Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
```

OK so then I tried the promising tomcat-jdbc library

```
<bean id="dataSource3" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="rootroot" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
</bean>
```

And the following similar exception pops up

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.ExtendedClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in KernelBundleClassLoader: [bundle=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc_1.1.0.1]
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:139)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
```

I am using the following persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ShiftManagement" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    ....
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <!-- Database options -->
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions" value="true"/>
        <!-- 
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1"/>
         -->                        

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="rootroot"/>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I inject the EntityManager using

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

I read some posts to remove the username and password from the persistence.xml but then the system complains there are that user = [null].

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: mysqld is running and I can connect using mysql -uroot -prootroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I used a fourth datasource and all my problems dissapeared :-)

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="${javax.persistence.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${javax.persistence.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657503/how-to-define-a-mysql-datasource-bean-via-xml-in-spring)

And in this case you see that the mysql driver is not found 
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shiftmanagement`

Comment: In my post I use three datasources, I tried the spring datasource which does not connect either.

Comment: @CoenDamen I have added some informations to my post

Comment: No, the no suitable driver error means the connection fails. This is always the case when connection fails to mysql. as you can see in my post, the datasource1 does not complain about the driver.