# Is it possible to define a datasource using jdbc from xml files?

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:crm_company.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
```

In this example I have a script in .sql file.My question is refering if can I use something equivalent with the script from .xml file.

Comment: Would this link be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657503/how-to-define-a-mysql-datasource-bean-via-xml-in-spring