# Spring + MyBatis - setting Data Source

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm integrating `MyBatis` inside my `SpringBoot` application. The application connects to a MySql database to fetch data. Right now I have the following classes.

**MyBatisUtils.java**

```
[...]
    @Component
    public class MyBatisUtils {

        private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory =
                new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(getConfiguration());

        public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory(){
            return sqlSessionFactory;
        }

        private static Configuration getConfiguration(){
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            DataSource dataSource = null; //wrong!!!
            TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
            Environment environment = new Environment("development", transactionFactory, dataSource);

            configuration.addMapper(BaseQuery.class);
            return configuration;
        }
    }
```

**Search.java**

```
[...]
    public List dynamicSearch(){

            SqlSession session = MyBatisUtils.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
            BaseQuery mapper = session.getMapper(BaseQuery.class);

            List<HashMap<String, Object>> result = mapper.select(/*query parameters*/);

            return result;
        }
```

I do not know how to set my `DataSource` object inside the `MyBatisUtils` class. Should it have some connection parameters? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Define the DataSource as a Spring bean, like in this other question:
[How to Define a MySql datasource bean via XML in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657503/how-to-define-a-mysql-datasource-bean-via-xml-in-spring)
Then inject the datasource in MyBatisUtils class.

You can also define SqlSessionFactory as a Spring bean, and directly inject it. Useful reference: http://www.mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `spring-boot` already you can use `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` and auto-configure mybatis for free. The only thing you should worry about is the datasource. For that, properties should be set in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

You can find more info [here](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/)